# FirefoxOS emulator and JSFiddle giving different result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, firefox-os

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/xFzy8/4/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<!-- ..................... Page 1 - HOME ..................... -->
<!-- ......................................................... -->
  <div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h3>My Test App</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
      <div class="container-wrapper">

        <!--
   ..................FOR TESTING ONLY..................
        <div class="container">
          <div data-role="collapsible" id="coll1">              
            <a href="#" class="btn-delete ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext" id="delColl1">Delete</a>
            <h3>Item 1</h3>
            <p>This is item 1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    ..................................................
        -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn-delete{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:2px;
    display:block !important;
    z-index:10000;
}

.ui-collapsible {
    position: relative;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var $containerWrapper = $('.container-wrapper');

/*..............FOR TESTING...................
    //var $btnDelItem1 = $('#delColl1').detach();
    //$('#coll1').append($btnDelItem1);
 ..............................................*/

    for(var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
      var $containerDiv = $('<div>', {'class':'container'})
      var $divCol = $('<div>', {'data-role':'collapsible', 'id':'coll'+i});
      var $btnDel = $('<a>', {'href':'#', 'class':'btn-delete ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext', 'id':'btnDel'+i});
      var $colHead = $('<h3>', {'text':'Item '+i});
      var $colContent = $('<p>', {'text':'This is item '+i});


      $containerDiv.append($divCol);  
      $divCol.append($colHead);
      $divCol.append($colContent);
      $containerWrapper.append($containerDiv);
      $containerWrapper.trigger('create');    
      $divCol.append($btnDel);
    }
  });
```

I am using the same code to run the webapp on firefoxOS emulator. But i am getting a different result. This is the result i'm getting on the emulator:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/208/mzv6.jpg

On JSFiddle, the Delete icon is appearing as it should. But on the emulator, the delete button is appearing below the collapsible headers. Even when i open the 'index.html' in a normal browser, im getting the same result as in the emulator.

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try these 2 things:

1 put the `btn-delete` class at the end of the list instead of first in the list of classes and see if it makes any difference.

2 Instead of the class, just use jQuery to set the CSS. After appending the created DOM elements, run this:

```
$btnDel.css({"position": "absolute", "top": "0", "right": "2px", "zIndex": "10000"});
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/xFzy8/6/)**

Also, instead of jQuery document.ready, use one of the jQM init events like:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function() {...
```

If jQM is still overriding your class, try appending the DOM elements in pageinit, and then set the CSS in pageshow.